# Forge Packets Out of Order

Tags: mysql, laravel, homestead, packets, laravel-forge

Getting an error

> called packets out of order

while trying to connect to a forge database from a local machine using homestead. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Cleanup title, call out explicit question, and add formatting on the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, you must whitelist your machine's IP address from Forge's firewall.

**Instructions:**

- Login to [Laravel Forge](https://forge.laravel.com)
- Click on your server and click on the **Network** tab located in the sidebar
- In the **NAME** field, enter MYSQL
- In the **PORT** field, enter 3306
- In the **From IP Address field**, enter your machine's IP address or leave blank to accept any incoming connections

Now click **ADD RULE** then wait about 10 seconds then refresh your application and it should work.

***I spent 3 hours trying to figure this out.***

**Even if you don't use Forge and still get this error, just adapt the instructions to whatever DB host you use and it should work.**